# How to update FlexLayout when ObservableCollection content changes

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

I'm new to Xamarin and struggle with displaying some fetched objects (Products in my case) as buttons into a FlexLayout.

Getting the result from the API and parsing it to objects (Products) is working fine as debugging shows that the ObservableCollection `Products` is filled with the products of the API.

I placed a label in the `ProductPage` which shows the amount of products in the `apiHelper.Products` list. This label is updated and shows the correct number of products after a while (the call and the parsing need to be completed first).

For some reason the `FlexView` content is not updated/"filled" with the products. When i initiate the `Products` list hardcoded so it contains products already when the view is initialized, the products are shown so the `FlexView` themselves seems to work fine.

My FlexView (placed in `ProductPage.xaml`):

```
... 
    # This label is updated when the fetch was succesfull!
<Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{ Binding Products.Count, StringFormat='Fetched products: {0}'}" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  BackgroundColor="#FF5959" TextColor="#EEF2FF" HorizontalTextAlignment="Right" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

...

     # The products are not shown when the fetch was successfull
<ScrollView Grid.Row="4">
    <FlexLayout 
    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
    x:Name="ProductsCollection"
    Wrap="Wrap"
    Direction="Row"
    JustifyContent="Center"
    AlignItems="Center"
    AlignContent="Start">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button
                    Text="{Binding button_description}"
                    WidthRequest="100"
                    Margin="10"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    BackgroundColor="#EEF2FF"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                    Clicked="addProductToOrder"
                />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </FlexLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The relevant code in the constructor of `ProductPage.xam.cs`:

```
public partial class ProductPage : ContentPage
{
  public ObservableCollection<Product> Products = { get; }
  private ApiHelper apiHelper; 

  public ProductPage(Order order) {
    ApiHelper apiHelper= new ApiHelper();
    _ = apiHelper.GetProductsAsync();
    this.Products = apiHelper.Products;
    BindingContext = this;
  }
```

My `ApiHelper` to fetch the products:

```
  private ObservableCollection<Product> _products = new ObservableCollection<Product> { };
  public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get => _products; set { _products = value; OnPropertyChanged("Products"); } } 

  public async Task<ObservableCollection<Product>> GetProductsAsync() {
    Uri baseAddr = new Uri("http://my.app/api/products");
    var client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(baseAddr).ConfigureAwait(false);
 
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
      Products.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Product>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())[0]);
    } 

    return Products;
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
```

Interestingly enough, when i replace the line:
`Products.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Product>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())[0])`
of the `ApiHelper` with: `Products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Product>>(await  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());`, the label is also not updated anymore. Probably because the `NotifyPropertyChanged` of the concerning list is not triggered then?

**My questions:**

- Why is my `FlexView` not updated/showing the products when the API call was successfull?
- How is it possible that the `Label` is updated but the `FlexLayout` isn't though they rely on the same list?
- Is it required to use `Products.add` or other array functions to make mutations to the array or should something like `Products = ....` also work?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from a few things I see, I believe the root cause of the problem is that there's no property changed event being fired in the ProductPage class. The best to set this up is to:

1. Change your ApiHelper class to just return a List or IEnumerable:

   ```
   public async Task<List<Product>> GetProductsAsync() {

       // previous logic to call api...

       var products = new List<Product>();

       if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
           products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())[0]);
       }

       return products;
   }
   ```
2. In your ProductPage, init the ObservableCollection once, then only add and remove from that instance:

   ```
   public partial class ProductPage : ContentPage
   {
     public ObservableCollection<Product> Products = { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
     private ApiHelper apiHelper; 

     public ProductPage(Order order) {
         ApiHelper apiHelper= new ApiHelper();
         var apiProducts = apiHelper.GetProductsAsync();
         foreach (var product in apiProducts) 
         {
             Products.Add(product);
         }
         BindingContext = this;
     }
    }
   ```

Didn't have VS in front of me, but the syntax should be close to accurate.

Also, note that GetProducts async is an async call, which means you may run into a blocking issue calling it from the ProductPage ctor. You'll probably want to fire the call from a method that you can make async. A common pattern is to add an "InitAsync" method in the ProductPage, then call it after you new up the page, but before you switch to it. Something like:

```
var productPage = new ProductPage();

await productPage.InitAsync();

NavController.SwitchPage(productPage); // Or whatever
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fire an `OnPropertyChanged` in the apiHelper class so maybe you are right and its not "reaching" the ProductPage. I tried your solution but the i receive the error: `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Task<List<Product>>' because 'Task<List<Product>>' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: You'll need to call `.Result()` on `apiHelper.GetProductsAsync` so that it returns the actual result instead of the task. As I noted in second part of my answer though, this will block the UI thread.